# webRTC blurred screen on iOS 13

Tags: ios, webrtc, ios13

webRTC blurred screen on `iOS 13`. How to fix.

I'm using `libjingle_peerconnection`,

https://cocoapods.org/pods/libjingle_peerconnection

connect with friend, I'm only see the blurred screen
but it work on iOS 12, just not work on iOS 13.

[image: blurred screen]

Comment: I got hit with the same issue, using Kurento SDK for iOS. After updating to GoogleWEBRTC i am now getting a black screen after switching to video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rtc_video_capture_ios_objc.mm: captureOutput
yPlaneBytesPerRow > CVPixelBufferGetWidth(videoFrame).
fix this stride issue with libyuv.

Comment: thanks, but actually I don't have ability to read and change the C code. I'm thanking should use GoogleWebRTC.

Comment: Hello @Alvin could you please share how you migrated to GoogleWebRTC from libjingle_peerconnection? Thanks and much appreciated!

Comment: I am use Cocoapods install Google webRTC, change a few code. https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/